# Unable to store value into string android

Tags: android

I would like to put the value to the `String array`, but it is unsuccessful.

I don't know what is the exact problem.

```
public String[] history = null;
    public String record;
    public int counter = 0;`

    public void createString (String record){       
        history[counter] = record;  
        counter++;
    }
```

Here is the defining variable.

What is the mistake i have done, and how to fix it ?

```
03-19 17:15:35.870: W/dalvikvm(4937): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c20450)


03-19 17:15:35.890: E/AndroidRuntime(4937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-19 17:15:35.890: E/AndroidRuntime(4937): java.lang.NullPointerException

03-19 17:15:35.890: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at com.airportapplication.app.Buses.createString(Buses.java:147)

03-19 17:15:35.890: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):     at com.airportapplication.app.Buses$1.onClick(Buses.java:101)
```

Comment: is it give any error ?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: 03-19 17:15:35.870: W/dalvikvm(4937): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c20450)
03-19 17:15:35.890: E/AndroidRuntime(4937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 17:15:35.890: E/AndroidRuntime(4937): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 17:15:35.890: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):  at com.airportapplication.app.Buses.createString(Buses.java:147)
03-19 17:15:35.890: E/AndroidRuntime(4937):  at com.airportapplication.app.Buses$1.onClick(Buses.java:101)

Comment: Please put your logcat error in the question. Its not readable here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your array
like this:

```
String[] history = new String[lengthOfArray];
```

if you don't know the array length use this:

```
List<String> history = new ArrayList<String>();
history.add(record);
```